# How to retrieve data from EditText created dynamically in android

Tags: android

How to retrieve data from EditText created dynamically in android

this is my exemple :

```
EditText val ;



    for(int i=0;i<alltowerslist.length();i++){

               JSONObject description = sub_towers.getJSONObject("description");
               String data2 =description.getString("data");



                       val=new EditText(Dynamique2.this);
                       val.setText(data2);
                       val.setId(i);
                       layout.addView(val); 
                       val.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                       }
```

Comment: getText() doesnt work?

Comment: there you have to make out a list of EditTexts.

Comment: then you can access throw their keys.

Comment: no show me how i do that please !!

Comment: val.getEdtiableText().toString() returns null?

Comment: but have more informations to retrieve  how i do that  loop?? if yes how ??

Answer (score 3):

Use the line of code

```
   EditText val[]=new EditText[alltowerslist.length()] ;
   String upDateVal[]=new String[val.length()] ;



        for(int i=0;i<alltowerslist.length();i++){

                   JSONObject description = sub_towers.getJSONObject("description");
                   String data2 =description.getString("data");



                           val[i]=new EditText(Dynamique2.this);
                           val[i].setText(data2);
                           val[i].setId(i);
                           layout.addView(val[i]); 
                           val[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                           }
```

now you can access them at which position editText detail you want.
for EX: `val[1].getText().toString()`

atEnd getting values from editTexts.

```
 for(int i=0;i<val.length();i++){        
                       upDateVal[i]=val[i].getText().toString();
 }
```

Comment: thank's for you answer but now if the user want to change the informations in EditText (data2) how i can retrieve the new information !!! it's my question

Comment: You have each editText in array then you can access them and update whole data.
if there you can't recognize which editText contains which information then you can make an array of ids too...